# Can't activate Python venv in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, command-prompt

I created a virtual environment with `python -m venv myenv` from the command prompt, but I don't know how to activate it. I tried executing `activate.bat` from the command prompt but it does not activate.

In other words, I don't see the current path changed to `(myenv) C:\Pathname...` to indicate that myenv has been activated. When I execute `activate.bat` the venv is not activated.

Comment: To clarify, you ran `myenv\Scripts\activate.bat`?

Comment: Yes that's correct, am I the only one experiencing this problem?

Comment: After running activate.bat, check whether the following prints the path to the virtual environment's python.exe: `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"`. Also check whether `VIRTUAL_ENV` is set to the activated environment path.

Comment: It shows `C:\Python34\python.exe`, not the one from the venv.

Comment: Looks like it works on PowerShell, thanks.

Comment: To clarify, you switched to using Activate.ps1 in PowerShell? But before you were definitely running cmd.exe and activate.bat didn't work?

Comment: Yeah, cmd.exe activate.bat doesn't work, but PowerShell Activate.ps1 works after changing the execution policy to unrestricted.

Comment: Activate.ps1 should work with the execution policy set to `RemoteSigned`. Anyway, if it's not too much trouble, could you edit your question to include the activate.bat file that doesn't work?

Comment: hmm... no wonder why it didn't work... `activate.bat` is an empty file 0KB! `Activate.Ps1` is not empty though. Don't know why, fresh Windows 10 install and followed the instructions for all the steps from the official python manual.

Comment: Check the template file. It should be `C:\Python34\Lib\venv\scripts\nt\activate.bat`.

Comment: That template exists 1KB. I just created another venv to test it and it works now in cmd.exe, I see a 1KB `activate.bat`. Don't know why the first venv I created had a 0KB `activate.bat`.

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem, file a bug on the issue tracker. Otherwise I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 7):

This thread it old but I had the same problem today and found a working answer for it.  I've been using python 3.6 venv for a few months now without issues but today I ran across a new error message:

```
C:\test>python -m venv vm
Error: Command '['C:\\test\\vm\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I scoured Stack and other resources for an answer but didn't find anything specific to Windows 10.  (AskUbunto had a solution that was specific to Linux).  I did find breadcrumbs spread out across the InterWebs and pieced this together.

You need this python script:  https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

1. Install your virtual environment as usual but without pip:

   python -m venv virtual --without-pip

This method will create all of the necessary files *including* the activate bat files.

2. Copy the get-pip.py file into the virtual\Scripts subdirectory
3. cd into the Scripts subdirectory and "activate" python Note: the cmd line should name the directory from which python was activated:

   (virtual) C:\test\virtual\Scripts>

(if it says (root), it's activated your core installation)

4. now execute the script

   C:\test\virtual\Scripts>python get-pip.py

once run, I typed:

```
(virtual) C:\test\virtual\Scripts>pip freeze
```

to generate a freeze list and verify proper installation.  It should return nothing, no error msg, no freeze list.

5. Then I installed flask, tried pip freeze and noted the return was only for flask and dependent files:

> (virtual) C:\test\virtual\Scripts>pip freeze
>   click==6.7
>   Flask==0.12.2
>   itsdangerous==0.24
>   Jinja2==2.9.6
>   MarkupSafe==1.0
>   Werkzeug==0.12.2

Comment: Does anyone know what causes Python/Windows to get into this state?

Comment: Actually, I had a custom Python file named "copy.py" in the root of my Python project. Renaming the file to something unique fixed the issue for me.