# There is no Pip installer in the selected environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've got a python project for which I'm using VS Code on Windows. I created a virtual environment (`py -3 -m venv .venv`). This all seems to be fine. When I activate (`.\.venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1` or `.\.venv\Scripts\activate.bat`) I see `(.venv)`. I can run `pip` in the activated environment or not. However, when I open a `.py` file there is a warning that there is no linter installed. I click install and then I get this:

[image: no Pip installer available error message]

I've tried creating the virtual env different ways. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31769863/cant-activate-python-venv-in-windows-10?answertab=active#tab-top) answer. No matter what I do I always get that error message. Any ideas would be great.

Comment: Something similar happened to me recently. It turned out that I had two versions of python installed (2.7 and 3.6) and I forgot to update the project's default interpreter. Not sure if this is your problem, but thought I'd mention it. CTRL+SHIFT+P -> Select Interpreter

Comment: Yup I did indeed do that but it still didn't work until I used the link in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Wow after about 3 hours of banging my head I found the answer here: http://timmyreilly.azurewebsites.net/python-pip-virtualenv-installation-on-windows/

Using that guide instead of the official vs code docs (where I got the `py -3 -m venv` command), VS Code was able to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

From [VSCode: There is no Pip installer available in the selected environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50993566/vscode-there-is-no-pip-installer-available-in-the-selected-environment)

> I have multiple python versions:
>
> - 2.7
> - 3.6
> - 3.7
>
> Tell the vscode/ visual studio code, which version to use: press the following (Show All Commands): `Ctrl + Shift + P` paste the
>   following: Python: Select Interpreter Select one of the version that
>   it shows, I have selected python 3.7.3 64-bit
>
> Update python path in settings: press `Ctrl +` , to open Settings search
>   for python.pythonPath change python to /usr/bin/python3.7

Note: For windows you will need to find your python path. Mine was `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Python37_64`

> I had pip but it was 2.7, but since I am choosing python 3, it's pip
>   needs to be installed Run the following command in Terminal: 
>   `apt-get install python3-pip`

I didn't have to install python pip as it was already installed.

> Restart vscode With the above steps, all issues got resolved. Hope
>   that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same issue. While I don't know what causes it, I've
found that creating the virtual environment using the Windows command prompt (using e.g. `py -3 -m venv .venv`) rather than via a terminal in VS Code successfully creates an environment that includes `pip` - then I can return to VS Code and work with it without issue.